# Binding Reappt service to a PHP application on bluemix

Tags: php, email, binding, ibm-cloud, push-reappt

I am trying to create an application on IBM Bluemix. I need it to have a functionality to send emails via the page. I came across a few articles that suggest using Reappt. But I am unable to bind this service to PHP.
Can someone please help me figure out how to bind the Reappt service to my PHP application?

Comment: You can't bind Reappt service to an application. You could create Reappt service as "unbound" service and get credentials from Reappt dashboard and use it in your application. Please refer to docs  http://developer.reappt.io/docs/manual/html/cloud/intro/cloud_provisioning_bluemix.html

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - 25/07/2016**

As of Reappt's latest update on Bluemix, service binding is now supported on Reappt. Once your application is created (assuming you have already provisioned a Reappt service), click on **Bind A Service Or API** on your application dashboard and select your Reappt service for binding.

[image]

Your VCAP_SERVICES should be updated, once the binding is complete, and will include the information and credentials associated with your Reappt service (this can be accessed through the Environment Variables tab).

---

Previously binding was unsupported in Reappt and an intermediary adapter between your Reappt instance and your PHP application was necessary.